# Prove $A\cap(B \Delta C)=(A \cap B)\Delta (A \cap C)$

Tags: elementary-set-theory, proof-writing

Prove $$A\cap(B \Delta C)=(A \cap B)\Delta (A \cap C)$$ without using Venn Diagram

My Try:

we have $$A\cap(B \Delta C)=A \cap((B\cup C)-(B \cap C))=A \cap \left((B \cup C) \cap (B \cap C)'\right)$$

$\implies$

$$A\cap(B \Delta C)=(A \cap (B \cup C))\cap (B' \cup C')$$

$\implies$

$$A\cap(B \Delta C)=((A \cap B)\cup (A \cap C))\cap (B' \cup C')$$

$\implies$

$$A\cap(B \Delta C)=((A\cap B)\cap (B' \cup C')) \cup ((A\cap C)\cap (B' \cup C'))$$

$\implies$

$$A\cap(B \Delta C)=(A \cap B \cap C')\cup (A \cap C \cap B')$$

$\implies$

$$A\cap(B \Delta C)=((A\cap B)-C)\cup ((A \cap C)-B)$$

Can we proceed from here?

Answer (score 3):

You can always avoid "algebra of sets" by proving two inclusions with some case distinguishing:

If $x \in A \cap (B \Delta C)$, this means that $x \in A$ and $x \in B \Delta C$, which has two cases: $x \in B, x \notin C$ or $x \in C, x \notin B$. In the former case $x \in A, x \in B ,x \notin C$, so $x \in A \cap B$, $x \notin A \cap C$,so $x \in (A \cap B) \Delta (A \cap C)$. The other case is similar, and then you've shown the inclusion $$A \cap (B \Delta C) \subseteq (A \cap B) \Delta (A \cap C)$$

The reverse inclusion is similar but subtly different: if $x \in (A \cap B) \Delta (A \cap C)$, then either $x \in A \cap B$ and $x \notin (A \cap C)$ or the other way around. Suppose we are in the first case, then $x \in A \cap B, x \notin A \cap C$, and so $x \in A$ and $x \in B$. Then $x$ cannot be in $C$, or else $x \in A \cap C$, which is not the case now. So as $x \in B$ but $x \notin C$ we know that $x \in B \Delta C$ and $x \in A$ was already known , so $x \in A \cap (B \Delta C)$. The other case $x \notin A \cap B, x \in B \cap C$ is quite similar, and so the other inclusion $$A \cap (B \Delta C) \supseteq (A \cap B) \Delta (A \cap C)$$ has been shown and we have equality.

If you really want to go algebraic:

You can also reduce it to an identity over $\{0,1\}$ by identifying a set $A \subseteq X$ with $\chi_A: X \to \{0,1\}$, where $\chi_A(x) = 0 $ for $x \notin A$ and $\chi_A(x) = 1 $ for $x \in A$ (using [characteristic functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Characteristic_function), which form a ring using pointwise addition (modulo $2$, so $1+1= 0$) and multiplication as operations)
And then note that $$\chi_{A \cap B} = \chi_A \cdot \chi_B$$ for all $A,B \subseteq X$ and $$\chi_{A \Delta B} = \chi_A + \chi_B$$ as well.

Then the required identity just follows from the usual distributivity of $\cdot$ over $+$ in $\{0,1\}$, which thus also holds in the ring of functions from $X$ to $\{0,1\}$:

$$\chi_{A\cap (B \Delta C)} = \chi_A \cdot \chi_{B \Delta C} = \chi_A\cdot (\chi_B + \chi_C) = \chi_A \cdot \chi_B + \chi_A \cdot \chi_C = \chi_{A \cap B} + \chi_{A \cap C}= 
\chi_{(A\cap B) \Delta (A \cap C)}$$

and using $\chi_A = \chi_B$ (as functions) iff $A= B$ (as sets). So we essentially use that $(\mathscr{P}(X), \cap, \Delta, \emptyset ,X)$ and $(\{0,1\}^X, \cdot, +, 0,1)$ are isomorphic unitary (Boolean) rings.

Answer (score 1):

Let us use the definition of the symmetric difference of two sets $A$ and $B$ as: $$A\Delta B = (A \setminus B) \cup (B \setminus A)$$

We have on the LHS: $$\begin{align} A\cap (B \Delta C) = A \cap((B \setminus C) \cup (C \setminus B)) = (A \cap (B \setminus C)) \cup (A \cap (C \setminus B)) \end{align}$$

Now, note that as set intersection distributes over set difference   (which can be easily verified), we have with us: $$\begin{align} = ((A \cap B) \setminus (A \cap C)) \cup ((A \cap C) \setminus (A \cap B)) = (A \cap B) \Delta (A \cap C) \end{align}$$ which is the RHS.

Answer (score 0):

TIP: In some cases it is easier to rewrite *both* the LHS and the RHS and try to get to the same expression 'in the middle', rather than starting with the LHS and trying to end up with the RHS. Your problem is exactly one of those cases. In fact, in the second to last step you were able to show that the LHS equals

$$(A \cap B \cap C')\cup (A \cap C \cap B')$$

I choose this as the 'target' expression since it seems 'simpler' to me than your very last expression. Indeed, this expression that is a union of intersections would be the equivalent of what in logic would be called a Disjunctive Normal Form: a canonical form to which expressions in logic are often reduced to.

Another small tip: Rather than writing

> $$A\cap(B \Delta C)=(A \cap (B \cup C))\cap (B' \cup C')$$
>
> $\implies$
>
> $$A\cap(B \Delta C)=((A \cap B)\cup (A \cap C))\cap (B' \cup C')$$
>
> $\implies$
>
> $$A\cap(B \Delta C)=((A\cap B)\cap (B' \cup C')) \cup ((A\cap C)\cap (B' \cup C'))$$

etc.

you can save some work by simply writing:

$$A\cap(B \Delta C)=$$

$$(A \cap (B \cup C))\cap (B' \cup C') =$$

$$((A \cap B)\cup (A \cap C))\cap (B' \cup C')$$

$$((A\cap B)\cap (B' \cup C')) \cup ((A\cap C)\cap (B' \cup C'))=$$

etc.

OK, so let's see if we can rewrite the RHS to our target expression:

$$(A \cap B)\Delta (A \cap C) =$$

$$((A \cap B)\cup (A \cap C)) - ((A \cap B)\cap (A \cap C)) =$$

$$(A \cap (B\cup C)) - (A \cap B \cap C) =$$

$$A \cap (B\cup C) \cap (A \cap B \cap C)' =$$

$$(B\cup C) \cap A \cap (A' \cup B' \cup C') =$$

$$(B\cup C) \cap ((A \cap A') \cup (A \cap B') \cup (A \cap C')) =$$

$$(B\cup C) \cap (\emptyset \cup (A \cap B') \cup (A \cap C')) =$$

$$(B\cup C) \cap ((A \cap B') \cup (A \cap C')) =$$

$$(B\cup C) \cap A \cap (B' \cup C') =$$

$$A \cap (B\cup C) \cap (B' \cup C') =$$

$$A \cap ((B \cap B') \cup (B \cap C') \cup (C \cap B') \cup (C \cap C')) =$$

$$A \cap (\emptyset \cup (B \cap C') \cup (C \cap B') \cup \emptyset) =$$

$$A \cap ((B \cap C') \cup (C \cap B')) =$$

$$(A \cap B \cap C')\cup (A \cap C \cap B')$$

Phew!  Now, do you see why it would have been much more difficult to do this just the other way around? (indeed, you were unable to ...) But, now that you have this, then if you really want to have a single derivation from LHS all the way to the RHS, you can simply reverse this whole thing once you get to the 'midpoint'.