# Prove a property of symmetric difference

Tags: elementary-set-theory, set-theory

Prove $A \cap (B∆C)=(A \cap B)∆(A \cap C)$

I tried to start from both sides and I also tried to use both definitions of the symmetric difference but I haven't been able to find the other half of the property

Comment: Try drawing some diagrams.

Comment: I only get as result the part of A that intersects with B and C

Comment: Try expanding the right hand side and use $A \triangle B = (A\cup B)\smallsetminus(A\cap B)$.

Comment: @nkh99 I get $[ A \cap (B \cup C)] - [A\cap(B\cap\ C)]$ and I don't know how to proceed

Comment: Perhaps you may check this post: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2587503/prove-a-capb-delta-c-a-cap-b-delta-a-cap-c